# Mosaic plot with variation by color and size in R

Tags: r, plot, mosaic

Here is my dataset

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(var_1 = sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), 1000, replace =TRUE), 
                 var_2 = sample(c(0,1), 1000, replace = TRUE))
df <- df %>% group_by(var_1) %>% summarize(count = n(),
                                             avg = mean(var_2))
```

I would like to create a plot similar to mosaic where size of square would correspond to `count` variable and color of a square would correspond to `avg` variable.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a "treemap". There is a library to create treemaps in `ggplot2`, called `treemapify`:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(treemapify)

df %>% ggplot(aes(area = count, fill = avg)) + geom_treemap()
```

[image]